# Prove that there exists $x_0$ in [0,1] such that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given: Let $f, g: [0,1] \to [0, \infty)$ be continuous functions satisfying $\max f(x)=max g(x)$, where $x\in [0,1]$.

I know that we have to construct a new function $h$, where $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. I also know that I have to apply the intermediate value theorem, but I just do not know how to apply it or where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $a$ and $b$ where $f$ and $g$ respectively attain their maxima.  What can you say about $h(a)$ and $h(b)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Suppose that the maximum value of $f(x)$ occurs when $x=a$ and the maximum value of $g(x)$ occurs when $x=b$.  Then
$$f(a)=\max f(x)=\max g(x)\ge g(a)$$
and
$$g(b)=\max g(x)=\max f(x)\ge f(b)\ .$$
Now let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ as you suggested.  Then $h(a)\ge0$ and $h(b)\le0$.  See if you can take it from here.  Good luck!